# Get all P Tags in the UL tags, Javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am racking my brain trying to figure out a regex for this. I have the following invalid html:

```
...some html tags above...

<p>Bullet points:</p>
<ul>
    <li/>
<p>point 1</p>
    <li/>
<p>point 2</p>
</ul>

<p>Other Bullet points:</p>
<ul>
    <li/>
<p>point 3</p>
    <li/>
<p>point 4</p>
</ul>

...some html tags below...
```

I'm trying to get all the data between the `<p></p>` tags that are within `<ul></ul>` tags and replace them with valid li tags. I.e. I plan to replace the above with the below:

```
...some html tags above...

<p>Bullet points:</p>
<ul>
    <li>point 1</li>
    <li>point 2</li>
</ul>

<p>Other Bullet points:</p>
<ul>
    <li>point 3</li>
    <li>point 4</li>
</ul>

...some html tags below...
```

Comment: I might approach it a different way. If you can get the innerHTML of all the ULs, strip the tags, then re-create them based on linebreaks as LIs inside the UL. You might just remove all `<li/>` then it would be easier to use the DOM to pull all the `<p>`s out of the '<ul>'s and replace them with `<li>`s

Comment: Why is the html broken to begin with? Is their no way to change the html before passing it to the view? Most browsers are gonna auto correct the broken HTML which makes it hard to fix it.

Comment: I am copying and pasting from a word editor into a draft.js editor and using handlePastedText to parse the xml from the word editor into valid html. @kodecount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do 2 RegeXp for that, first to get the inner HTML of the UL tags, and then replace the P tags with LI tags.

First  get all `UL` tags:

```
var UL_tags=/<ul>([\s\S]*?)<\/ul>/g
// [\s\S] Mean any char including new lines.
```

Now, all you have to do:

```
new_html=myHtml.replace(UL_tags,function(r0,innerHTML){
    return innerHTML.replace(/<p>/g,'<ul>').replace(/<\/p>/g,'</ul>')
})
```

Be aware that it is not working for nested UL tags (UL inside UL)

**UPDATE:** Now, you need to support attributes inside the UL, for example: `<ul class...>` so we need to ignore the tag attributes, so the Regexp need to be little more complicated (sorry):

```
 var UL_tags=/<ul[^>]*?>([\s\S]*?)<\/ul>/g
 // [^>] Mean any char except closing tag.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in jQuery:

```
$('p').each(function(index){
    p_str = $(this).text();
    ....
})
```